# How receives array input parameters in SpringMvc?

Tags: spring-mvc

This is my request :

`https://mapapi.xxxxx.cn/get?runtimes[]=test1&runtimes[]=test2`

In PHP,I can get an array by `$_GET['runtimes']`

but in SpringMVC,How can I do?

This is my test:

```
@GetMapping("/get")
public String get(
@RequestParam(name = "runtimes[]", required = false) String[] runtimes,
){
    System.out.println(runtimes);
}
```

But I get an error `Error parsing HTTP request header`.

if replace `runtimes[]` by `runtimes`,it will get null.

Answer (score 0):

Your Spring controller should be like below

```
@GetMapping("/get")
    public String get(@RequestParam(name = "runtimes[]", required = false) String[] runtimeArray){
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(runtimeArray));
        return "test";
    }
```

and your request should be like this

```
https://mapapi.xxxxx.cn/get?runtimes[]=test1&runtimes[]=test2
```

My output is

```
[test1, test2]
```